# boolean expression of a list

Tags: python, list, count, boolean

What do I need to do when I want to return `True` when the elements in a list are all the same 
and `False` when there is one element not the same?

For example:

```
>>> f([3, 3, 3])
True  
>>> f([3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3])
False
```

I tried to make a `for` loop:

```
for i in My_list: 
    if i = ?: 
        return False  
    else: 
        return True
```

but I don't know what I need to write in `?`.

Comment: Personally, I'd set a variable for the first value in a list, and check all the other elements against it in a condition, returning False if any are different. Then have a `return True` statement outside of that for if `False` is never returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

```
try:
    all(my_list[0] == elem for elem in my_list[1:])
except IndexError:
    (Whatever you prefer)
```

or

```
len(set(my_list)) == 1
```

Comment: thanks volcano! your len(set(my_list)) == 1 was very usefull!

Answer (score 1):

Python has a [`set` type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) that only holds unique elements; as long as your list elements will always be hashable (`int`s are), you can test the length of the resulting set:

```
>>> def all_the_same(l):
    return len(set(l)) == 1

>>> all_the_same([3, 3, 3])
True
>>> all_the_same([3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3])
False
```

If `all_the_same([])` should also return `True`, make it `<= 1`.

---

Note that to do this with a `for` loop, it's `False` if *any* elements don't match, and only `True` if *all* elements match. So that would look something like:

```
def all_the_same(l):
    for x in l:
        if x != l[0]:
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods, the IMO cutest one being:

```
def f(lst):
    return lst[1:]==lst[:-1]
```

This basically checks if the list stays the same if you rotate it by one, which is true if and only if all elements are equal:

```
A B C D E F G 
  A B C D E F G
```